# purpose of defn in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm a little puzzled about the role of defn. If fn only produced anonymous functions, I could understand the need for a construct that combines the functionality of def and fn, but fn can also create named functions. At least in the repl, I don't see how that usage differs from defn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you provide a name symbol to `fn`, it's *only bound within the function definition to the function object itself*. This is to allow anonymous functions to call themselves ([Clojure - special forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms#fn)).

So to create a function with `fn` bound to a global accessible name, you have to use

```
(def somename 
    (fn ...body...
```

and `defn` is just a shortcut for this.

```
(defn somename 
    ...body...
```

---

In response to your comment, from a fresh repl:

```
Give me some Clojure:
> (fn foo [] (+ 1 3))
#<sandbox31764$eval31779$foo__31780 sandbox31764$eval31779$foo__31780@12eae8eb>
> (foo)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context
> (defn foo [] (+ 1 3))
#'sandbox31764/foo
> (foo)
4
>
```

As you can see, I can't call the `foo` function created with `fn`, because it's not bound to a Var.

Comment: Same question as below: If the fn name symbol is internally bound, why can I call it from the repl?

Comment: Maybe there's already a Var with that name? Have you tried resetting your repl? I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Planarian Please post the code you enter in a fresh REPL so that you get the behavior you describe.

Comment: You're right. I cleared my session, reloaded the function, and got an error (as you predicted). I didn't intentionally define a var, so it's a bit of a mystery....

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that `defn` creates a global name, wheres `fn` only creates a lexical one. The global name is also a var, since it's ultimately created with `def`. The name you can give to an anonymous function is not a var and is only within scope of that function. This is mostly so the function can be recursive.

Comment: But if the scope of the name created by fn is internal to the function, why can I call it from the repl?

Comment: You can't. 
(fn bingo [] (println "bingo"))